# Как вызвать команду Command="Copy" из ContextMenu Click?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, click

Команда копировать тест Copy (в Button) связана через  Command с ApplicationCommands.Copy

Как вызвать команду Command="Copy" из ContextMenu Click?

Click Пытается найти команду в Window1 а не в ApplicationCommands.Copy.

> Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
>   Ошибка    CS1061  'Window1" не содержит определения для "Copy" и не
>   удалось найти метод расширения "Copy", принимающий тип "Window1" в
>   качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или
>   ссылка на
>   сборку). \Window1.xaml    1365    Активно

```
<Button Command="Copy">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock />                    
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy, OnCopy, CanCutOrCopy));
TextAreaDefaultInputHandler.WorkaroundWPFMemoryLeak(InputBindings);
```

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Click="Copy">
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено заменой Click на Command

```
<MenuItem  Command="Copy"   >
```

Answer (score 1):

Как решить, вы уже написали, а я допишу, почему такое происходит.

Превращение текста `"Copy"` в `ApplicationCommands.Copy` производится при помощи type converter'а. Type converter в команду действительно ищет среди `ApplicationCommands.*`. Но тип `Click` — не команда, а событие, поэтому правила для команд здесь не действуют.